# SQL Big Query - Add new column to table with query results?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, latitude-longitude

I'd like to take two columns (latitude and longitude) and create a single column with the combined information. The final goal is (a) see if I can gather useful information about these locations and (b) create a map visualization with all of these coordinates.

I've successfully queried and gotten the combined latitude/longitude information with this query -

SELECT
CONCAT(lat, lng) AS lat_lng
FROM `dataset.abc.xyz`

And created a new column

ALTER TABLE `dataset.abc.xyz`
ADD COLUMN latlng

But I can't figure out how to get the information from the query into the new column. Or is there a different process entirely that I should be doing?

Comment: It did not work for me in a free version, google asked me to update my billing in order to use as they called "DML" commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an update:

```sql
UPDATE dataset.abc.xyz
SET latlng = CONCAT(CAST(lat AS STRING), CAST(lng AS STRING))
WHERE lat IS NOT NULL;
```

But note that this column may actually not be necessary since it can easily be computed from the latitude and longitude columns.  So, you might find that not adding this column can also work for you.

Comment: Thank you! This seemed like it would work, but the BigQuery error says that it needs a WHERE clause. I'm not sure how to phrase a WHERE when you want all of the rows concatenated without restriction.  I tried several things like using a lat >30 as a restriction based on my set of coordinates, and using another string-based column with only a few options as reference in a WHERE clause. For now, I'm taking your suggestion of not creating a new column for the lat/long. But I still need to figure this out for other columns I want to combine in this dataset. So easy in Excel, I know I can do this.

Comment: Figured out the WHERE clause thing - WHERE lat IS NOT NULL.  BigQuery says Value of type STRING cannot be assigned to latlng. Schema confirms that lat, lng and latlng are all FLOAT datatype. So I'm going to dig a little deeper on that and see if I can get it to work. Thanks again.